# how to pass environment variable in kubectl deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am setting up the kubernetes setup for django webapp.

I am passing environment variable while creating deployment as below

```
kubectl create -f deployment.yml -l key1=value1
```

I am getting error as below

```
error: no objects passed to create
```

Able to create the deployment successfully, If i remove the env variable -l key1=value1 while creating deployment.

deployment.yaml as below

```
#Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
 labels: 
   service: sigma-service
 name: $key1
```

What will be the reason for causing the above error while creating deployment?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I used envsubst (https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) for this. Create a `deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: $NAME
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Then:

```
export NAME=my-test-nginx
envsubst < deployment.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Not sure what OS are you using to run this. On macOS, envsubst installed like:

```
brew install gettext
brew link --force gettext
```

Comment: you can also use the sed command if your image doesn't come with envsubst installed, see comments on https://stackoverflow.com/a/56005832/11239755

Comment: This won't work in a shell script though, how do I inject variables set in a shell script?

Answer (score 16):

You cannot pass variables to "kubectl create -f". YAML files should be complete manifests without variables. Also you cannot use "-l" flag to "kubectl create -f".

If you want to pass environment variables to pod you should do like that:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        env:
        - name: MY_VAT
          value: MY_VALUE
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Read more here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/

Comment: I need to change the name of the deployment dynamically so need to pass environment variable to deployment @Vasily Angapov

Comment: again, with "kubectl create -f" it is impossible. Rather you use "kubectl run" with parameters or you use Helm chart.

Comment: How can i achieve using Helm?@Vasily Angapov

Comment: It's too wide topic to discuss. You can read more here: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/#the-chart-template-developer-s-guide

Answer (score 13):

This isn't  a right way to use the deployment, you can't provide half details in yaml and half in kubectl commands. If you want to pass environment variables in your deployment you should add those detail in the `deployment spec.template.spec`:

You should add following block to your deployment.yaml

```
spec:
  containers:
  - env:
    - name: var1
      value: val1
```

This will export your environment variables inside the container.

The other way to export the environment variable is use kubectl run (not advisable) as it is going to be depreciated very soon. You can use following command:

```
 kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --restart=Always --replicas=1 --env=var1=val1
```

The above command will create a deployment nginx with replica 1 and environment variable `var1=val1`

Comment: And what if you are using some kind of CI/CD? How would you say witch version or tag of the image to deploy?

Comment: According to 
[k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#run)

Example:
`kubectl run hazelcast --image=hazelcast/hazelcast --env="DNS_DOMAIN=cluster" --env="POD_NAMESPACE=default"`

Answer (score 7):

Follow the below steps

create test-deploy.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: MYAPP
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

using sed command you can update the deployment name at deployment time

```
sed -e 's|MYAPP|my-nginx|g' test-deploy.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: Sed is what I use too, it is in (probably?) every distro.

Comment: yes it is see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145229 AND for dynamic variable replacement do this:
export MYVAR=1234 then sed 's/wantReplaced/'"${MYVAR}"'/'.... etc

Answer (score 0):

File: `./deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: MYAPP
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
      ports:
      - containerPort: 80
```

File: `./service.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: MYAPP
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

File: `./kustomization.yaml`

```
resources:
- deployment.yaml
- service.yaml
```

If you're using https://kustomize.io/, you can do this trick in a CI:

```
sh '( echo "images:" ; echo "  - name: $IMAGE" ; echo "    newTag: $VERSION" ) >> ./kustomization.yaml'
sh "kubectl apply --kustomize ."
```

Answer (score -1):

I chose `yq` since it is yaml aware and gives a precise control where text substitutions happen.

To set an image from bash env var:

```
export IMAGE="your_image:latest"
yq eval '.spec.template.spec.containers[0].image = "'$IMAGE'"' manifests/daemonset.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

`yq` is available on MacPorts (as of 19/04/21 v4.4.1) with `sudo port install yq`

Answer (score -2):

Please try following

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: kdpd00201
  name: frontend
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 6
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: frontend
        image: ifccncf/nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8001
        env:
           - name: NGINX_PORT
             value: "8001"
```

Answer (score -2):

I was facing the same problem. I created a python script to change simple/complex or add values to the YAML file.
This became very handy in a similar situation that you describe. Also, switching to the python domain can allow for more complex scenarios.

The code and how to use it are available at this gist.
https://gist.github.com/washraf/f81153270c80b0b4ecf90a53872abde7

Answer (score -3):

My solution is then

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: frontend
  name: frontend
  namespace: kdpd00201
spec:
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null      
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - env: # modified level
        - name: NGINX_PORT
          value: "8080"
        image: lfccncf/nginx:1.13.7
        name: nginx
        ports:  
          - containerPort: 8080
```