# How to pass dynamic value to kubernetes container

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am new to Kubernetes and I have a simple python code which is a sum of two numbers and deployed in Kubernetes.
I want to pass two values dynamically to Kubernetes running container.
My Code:

```py
import sys

number1 = int(sys.argv[1])

number2 = int(sys.argv[2])

print(number1 + number2)
```

I want to pass number 1 and number 2 dynamically each time with different numbers.
Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

In your pod spec field there are fields to pass in arguments to your command. If you are using a different type of kubernetes kind (deployment, daemonset ...) that kind has a template field for your pod spec. This [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/) has a good description of what you are trying to do.

In short you need to provide an argument field to your pods spec.

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: your-containers-name
    image: image
    command: ["python", "app.py"]
    args: 
      - "234" # number1
      - "433" # number2
```

Comment: If I want to change values from 234 to something else, Again do i need to edit pods spec.
Is there a way to pass those changes dynamically from command line

Comment: You can do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56009991/2430915, or use sed to update the yaml before piping it to kubectl. The other option you could use is the `kubectl run` command which might look something like this `kubectl run nginx --image=nginx -- <arg1> <arg2> ... <argN>`