# how to pass a namespace to a subject in a rolebinding in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I have the following manifest:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: my-psp-rb
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: psp-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
- kind: Group
  name: system:serviceaccounts:${NAMESPACE}
```

I would like to deploy this manifest as follows:
`kubectl apply -f psp-rb.yaml -n some_namespace`
in a way that the name in the subject is dynamically set. I know that `${NAMESPACE}` is not allowed, so I am looking for a way on how to do this. I looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56003777/how-to-pass-environment-variable-in-kubectl-deployment) but I am not a huge fan of installing dependencies only for passing variables to a manifest (plus I agree variables shouldn't be used in this context). Maybe there is a kubernetesy way to do this?

Comment: the only ways I see would be to use either Helm or Kustomize

Comment: that's what i thought :'(

Comment: there's no downwards api on Rolebindings, so yeah, no choice.

Answer (score 1):

Copying down from comments and confirming, this is not a thing kubectl supports. It's very simple :)