# How do I route/forward RESTful localhost calls from one specific replica set to another, without globally exposing a port?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

Basically, what I am trying to do is imagine you have one replica set. This replica set called A contain pods that 'post' to localhost:9000, now I have another replica set B whose pods listen to localhost:8080. I want to divert the calls made to localhost:9000 on A to replica set B to port 8080. The only caveat is if I have another replica set C whose pods also listen to port 8080 they should not receive the traffic. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyU0M.png

Comment: In Kubernetes, you normally utilize the built-in name server and other primitives like services.

Comment: Ya I thought this was what I thought I might have to do just hardcode it through service DNS. Can you provide a concrete example how do you reference the name of a service. Would it be like this curl (http://<service name>:<port>). However, I'm still seeking kubernetes only configuration, and or alternatives/concrete examples.

Comment: a service is a "kubernetes only" configuration.

Comment: This would require me too hardcode changes in my codebase.

Comment: Your codebase should be configurable with environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define a service for B. For A, instead of posting to localhost, post using the name of service B will do. C can have a service that use the same port but will NOT get traffic because A explicitly post to service B.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: app-b
  name: service-b  # <-- name of this service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: app-b
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 9000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
```

`curl -XPOST http://service-b:9000` <-- neither pod nor service belongs to C will ever get this request

Comment: As this would get the job done this would require me to hardcode changes in my codebase and create new images.

Comment: There are many ways to pass info such as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56003777/how-to-pass-environment-variable-in-kubectl-deployment). Your app can then use the info instead of hardcode.

Comment: That's true, interesting route/work around, and perspective thanks, helped alot.