# Use environment variable inside nx project.json

Tags: angular, nx-workspace

I'm using [nx](https://nx.dev/) as my monorepo management tool, which contains typescript apis and angular frontends.
Now i'm trying to get my project running inside [github codespaces](https://github.com/features/codespaces).

Everything works fine except the angular applications, when I try to serve them.
The I get and error `Invalid Host/Origin header`.
This issue can be resolved using the [`--public-host`](https://angular.io/cli/serve) flag.

This is how I can now server my angular applications using the codespaces environment variable `CODESPACE_NAME` and nx cli:

```
npx nx serve application --publicHost=${CODESPACE_NAME}-4080.githubpreview.dev:443
```

My question is now, if it's possible to configure a new target inside `project.json` to serve my application like `npx nx run application:codespaces`?

I already tried to create a new target but it does not resolve the environment variable:

```
...
 "codespaces": {
  "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "browserTarget": "console:build:production"
    },
    "development": {
      "browserTarget": "console:build:development"
    }
  },
  "defaultConfiguration": "development",
  "options": {
    "publicHost": "${CODESPACE_NAME}-4080.githubpreview.dev:443",
    "port": 4080
  }
},
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted by [@Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19980474/jonathan-kolyer), the option strings are not pre-processed by many default executors. Either you can create your own [custom executors](https://nx.dev/recipes/executors/creating-custom-executors) where you process the options using the environment variable values and customize your application execution.

Example:

```
import { ExecutorContext } from '@nrwl/devkit';
import { RunCommandExecutorSchema } from './schema';

export default async function runExecutor(
    options: RunCommandExecutorSchema,
    context: ExecutorContext
) {
    console.log('Executor ran for RunCommand', options);

    // process env vars within options
    options = JSON.parse(
        JSON.stringify(options)
            .replace(/\$(\w+)/g, (_, key) => process.env[key] || '')
            .replace(/'/g, '"')
    ) as RunCommandExecutorSchema;

    console.log('Executor ran for RunCommand', options);

    // run @angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server with this context now
    
    return {
        success: true
    };
}
```

Btw, if you are using custom [run commands](https://nx.dev/packages/nx/executors/run-commands), then you will have access to all the environment variables declared in .env file as mentioned in the [docs](https://nx.dev/recipes/environment-variables/define-environment-variables) here.

Example:

```
"echo": {
    "executor": "nx:run-commands",
    "options": {
        "command": "echo $SOME_ENV_VAR",
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to pre-process the JSON file using the approach [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56003777/how-to-pass-environment-variable-in-kubectl-deployment/56009991#56009991).

```
    export FOO=foobar 
    echo {"foo": "$FOO"} > myjson.json 
    envsubst < myjson.json
```

```
    output: {foo: foobar}
```