# Using env variable inside yaml deployment file in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

How do I use env variable defined inside deployment? For example, In yaml file dow below I try to use env CONT_NAME for setting container name, but it does not succeed. Could you help please with it, how to do it?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: $CONT_NAME
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        env:
        - name: CONT_NAME
          value: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variables to set values inside deployment natively. If you want to do that you have to process the file before executing the kubectl, take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56003777/how-to-pass-environment-variable-in-kubectl-deployment). The best option to do this which it's focused on parametrize and standardize deployments is to use [Helm](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/variables/)

Answer (score 0):

In those situations I just replace the `$CONT_NAME` in the yaml with the correct value right before applying the yaml.

`sed -ie "s/\$COUNT_NAME/$COUNT_NAME/g" yourYamlFile.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

If your using fluxcd, it has the ability to do variable interpolation [link](https://fluxcd.io/flux/components/kustomize/kustomization/#variable-substitution)